# Function names with property lookups in JScript 5.8 / WSH

Tags: javascript, jscript, wsh

I was looking at Windows Script Host code that runs in JScript 5.8 and I noticed this construct:

```
function String.prototype.foo() { ... }
```

I can't find any documentation about it! I'm fairly sure this is not legal in EcmaScript, so it has to be a Microsoft-only extension. Does anyone have any links explaining its design and semantics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JScript team released a draft of a document [on their blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jscript/2007/10/29/ecmascript-3-and-beyond/) called "JScript Deviations from ES3" that describes this syntax among others.

From section 4.4:

> JScript permits function names to be qualified. This allows for `function foo.prototype()` to be syntactic sugar for `foo.prototype = function (){}` Note that the object on LHS of the '.' must already be defined.

On [this post from IEBlog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2010/06/25/enhanced-scripting-in-ie9-ecmascript-5-support-and-more/) about IE9 and ECMAScript 5 compatibility, they mention that this syntax is not supported by IE9 standards mode. I would imagine the same holds true for later versions of IE as well.